# How can I add an authentication header to a SOAP request using Zeep in Python?

Tags: python, soap-client, zeep

I am using a REST API to get the access token for the endpoint.
It works perfectly well when I try to use this following header in postman

```
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <fueloauth xmlns="http://">{the access token}</fueloauth>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
```

How do I add this authentication while using Zeep?

Tried using the Transport element

```
session = Session()
session.headers["Authorization"] = f"Bearer {access_token}"
transport = Transport(session=session)
```

Also, tried adding a header but the it throws an error saying the Security Header is missing

```
fueloauth = ET.Element("{http://}fueloauth", access_token)
response = client.service.Method(
          _soapheaders=fueloauth, Method=json
         )
```